# How to dispose of engine coolant?

Tags: coolant

This question is pretty straight forward...
How to properly dispose of engine coolant? Should it be taken to a treatment facility like used engine oil or is it safe to pour down the drain?

Comment: Add it to cheap French wine... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1985_diethylene_glycol_wine_scandal

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do not pour it down the drain, and do not pour it outside. Coolant is very sweet tasting to animals and they will "drink" it. It will affect both their kidneys and GI tract with potentially fatal consequences if not treated. Typical symptoms include vomiting, thirst, lack of appetite and unusual lethargy.

If you pour it down the drain, it will pollute things downstream from your sewage facility.  If you have a septic system, it will foul it up.

Take it to a recycling/collection center.

Comment: What if it's very diluted? Like 9 parts water 1 part old coolant? Would it still  pollute any more than the shampoo that goes down the drain?

Comment: Ethylene glycol is a different compound from shampoo and soap, and it hangs around much longer.  Recycle it. Don't dump it.

Comment: If you go to the EPA site, you'll see that they recommend recycling it due to its connection to natural gas. They link to www.earth911.com for those seeking recycling information.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your description of the animal consequences is off.  ["In the first few hours after ingestion the pet may be depressed and staggering and may have seizures. They may drink lots of water, urinate large amounts and vomit. The pet may appear to feel better but in a day or two get much worse as the kidneys fail. Signs of kidney failure include depression and vomiting. The amount of urine they pass will often decrease to a very small amount."](http://bit.ly/1Q7lOlq) If you notice the first symptoms, take your pet to the vet immediately where they can do blood and urine tests.

Comment: Do not get it on your skin. I had an unfortunate occurrence years ago where while under my car, I struck a coolant hose, which broke and my right arm was heavily coated with coolant. I washed it off but I suffered from irritability and mild depression for at least two days - it was a very odd experience and I now treat coolant as it is labelled - a poison.

Comment: Also, note that some auto parts stores will take used antifreeze for recycling.

Answer (score 12):

**Check your location's laws, but the EPA says it's not hazardous waste.**  If you're just a DIY-er, you can probably pour it down your toilet.  Try and find a recycler first though.

In St. Louis, MO (my example), I have not found a better way for a DIY-er to dispose of it, but I believe professional shops have some way to dispose of it not accessible to us.

There *are* places in Missouri that accept antifreeze for recycling, such as [Springfield](http://mo-springfield.civicplus.com/DocumentCenter/View/3179) and [Clay County collection centers](https://www.claycountymo.gov/Services/Recycling), but you have to be a resident with proof and there are limits on the amounts.

### EPA, DNR, CDC etc.:

The [EPA](http://www.epa.gov/airtoxics/hlthef/ethy-gly.html) does not consider used coolant to be a hazardous waste.  None of the major auto parts stores accept it for recycling.  St. Louis, MO's household hazardous waste center does not accept it because it is not a hazardous waste.

The [EPA (different link)](http://www.epa.gov/wastes/conserve/materials/antifree.htm) says some states consider used antifreeze hazardous because after being run through your engine, it can contain lead, cadmium, chromium, mercury,  kryptonite, etc.

Used antifreeze can be determined not to be hazardous by simply knowing where it came from.  Testing is not needed to classify it as hazardous waste.  If it has not been used in a old vehicle, heavy machinery, nuclear plant, etc., it can be called non-hazardous by whoever is disposing of it.

[Here is a rundown](http://infohouse.p2ric.org/ref/27/26530.pdf) of what is acceptable for each state *including dumping it down the sanitary sewer*.  Some states have deemed it hazardous, but not most.

The [Missouri Department of Natural Resources](http://dnr.mo.gov/pubs/pub114.htm) says, "if the facility is connected to a sanitary sewer that discharges to a Publicly Owned Treatment Works (POTW) and the wastes will mix with domestic sewage, the waste antifreeze may be disposed in the sanitary sewer on-site."  And that exact text is seen repeatedly when searching about this subject.  They do say you need to check with your sewer company, but since no permit is required, I assume that is legal covering their butts.

The [CDC](http://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/phs/phs.asp?id=84&tid=21) says that ethylene glycol will break down in a few weeks when not in our cars' closed systems, i.e. when exposed to air.  Antifreeze contains more than just ethylene glycol though.  It contains O2 inhibitors (buffering and alkalinity type stuff), but those will be depleted quickly when exposed to the open atmosphere.  I do not know what chemicals it breaks down to though, but they are apparently not bad enough to mention.  We're not chemists on this site so we should just follow the government agencies' policies.

**Please open the two EPA links and search for the word "hazardous".**  The EPA does not consider antifreeze to be hazardous if it is not contaminated, i.e. it has only been used in a newer consumer vehicle.

Comment: This is incorrect. I am looking at the EPA site on recycling used antifreeze and it is clearly hazardous and they definitely do not recommend putting it in any water supply.

Comment: @BobCross Which EPA site are you looking at?

Comment: @BobCross The "toilet" disposal for small amounts is no myth.  That is *completely* different than pouring down a storm drain.  Local rules may vary, but ethylene glycol will be processed by sewage treatment.  I'm not suggesting this is the **best** solution, only that in many cases it's not an *illegal* one.  How one determines how much babbiting and other heavy metals might be contained therein is beyond me.  Being an environmental type of guy, I filter mine through a stack of old mattresses and then a final through clean Wonderbread, and sell it back to my frugal customers...

Answer (score 4):

Your local landfill may have a spot to dispose of oil and antifreeze.

In my city, it is illegal to dump antifreeze in the trash or on the ground.

Answer (score -3):

Coolant is toxic. If human intake it then they will suffer soon and will develop cancer in a year.  So it should be quite toxic to animals. In big picture, we should not produce such toxic liquid to begin with but just dumping in toilet is no good.

Comment: "If human intake it then they will suffer soon and will develop cancer in a year." That's a very bold claim. Is there any research related to how fast coolant gives humans cancer?

Comment: @Davide - From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene_glycol_poisoning) - *Ethylene glycol poisoning is poisoning caused by drinking ethylene glycol. Early symptoms include intoxication, vomiting and abdominal pain. Later symptoms may include a decreased level of consciousness, headache, and seizures. Long term outcomes may include kidney failure and brain damage. Toxicity and death may occur even after drinking a small amount.* It states elsewhere, acute kidney failure can occur within 72 hours if enough is ingested.

Comment: So, no time to develop cancer...